# How to access foreign key table in jooq?

Tags: java, postgresql, foreign-keys, jooq

I have two tables:
real_estate: id - PK, external_id_mdm

key_transfer: id - PK, real_estate_id - FK (references real_estate (id))

in my jooq update query i want to update and get returning type:

```
    dsl.update(keyTransfer)
                    .set(keyTransfer.SEND_OGO, ogo)
                    .where(keyTransfer.ID.eq(keyTransferId))
                    .returning(keyTransfer.realEstate().EXTERNAL_ID_MDM)
                    .fetchOneInto(String.class);
```

Which gives me error:
Column "alias_30603682"."external_id_mdm" has been requested through the returning() clause, which is not present in table "key_transfer".

The message says something like I am accessing the key_transfer table, but indeed i am accessing real_estate through FK.

Few times in past i requested such kind of request in Select queries, and it worked. What's wrong this time?

I am expecting to get field external_id_mdm through FK as String type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.19, implicit join from DML `RETURNING` clauses is not yet supported, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13630

You have to join the `REAL_ESTATE` table explicitly using [`UPDATE .. FROM`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/update-from/), like this:

```java
dsl.update(KEY_TRANSFER)
   .set(KEY_TRANSFER.SEND_OGO, ogo)
   .from(REAL_ESTATE)
   .where(KEY_TRANSFER.ID.eq(keyTransferId))
   .and(KEY_TRANSFER.REAL_ESTATE_ID.eq(REAL_ESTATE.ID))
   .returningResult(REAL_ESTATE.EXTERNAL_ID_MDM)
   .fetchOneInto(String.class);
```

Note that in order to fetch a `Record1<String>` consisting of only the `EXTERNAL_ID_MDM` column, you'll have to use `returningResult()`, not `returning()`. [See the relevant Javadoc for details](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/UpdateReturningStep.html#returning(org.jooq.SelectFieldOrAsterisk...)).

Comment: thank you, Lukas. As always brilliant answer